# How to use lambda expression in jrxml file?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, jasper-reports

I am trying to use lambda expression inside *jrxml* file to get values for my field.

I imported appropriate classes but it is giving me error that

> p cannot be resolved to a variable.

How to use a lambda expression inside *JasperReports*'s templates?.

```
<textFieldExpression>
    <![CDATA[StringUtils.join(((Collection<Property>)((Object2)$F{field1}.getPropertyValue("property1")).getPropertyValue("property2")).stream().map(p->((Object1)p.getValue()).getName()).collect(toList()),',');]]>
</textFieldExpression>
```

Exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. p cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the Eclipse JDT compiler, first make sure that you have a fairly recent version.

You can get 4.5.1 from [Maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler%22%20AND%20a%3A%22ecj%22) for instance, then add the following properties to your jasperreports.properties file:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8
```

Comment: If anyone is having the same issue. I added the eclipse jdt compiler dependency and added jasperreports.properties file with the settings specified at the root level in the resources folder.