# Jasper Report syntax error on compiling

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, jasper-reports, ireport

- Jasper report - Netbeans latest plugin for ireport ([plugin for 7.4](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/4425/ireport))
- JDK - 1.8
- Netbeans 8.2

I am using java 8 streams inside the jrxml file. Stream function working fine outside the jrxml and when I compile the report It gives me below error :

```
Compilation exceptions: com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.ErrorsCollector@3155ed77

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
.sorted(java.util.Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getId())) //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                                         ^
2. Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
.filter(p -> !p.isIsComplete()).filter(p -> p.isStatus()) //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
          ^
3. Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
.filter(p -> !p.isIsComplete()).filter(p -> p.isStatus()) //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                                         ^
4. Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
.filter(com.court.handler.FxUtilsHandler.distinctByKey(p -> p.getMemberLoanCode())) //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                                                         ^
5. Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
.sorted(java.util.Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getId())) //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                                         ^
6. Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
.filter(p -> !p.isIsComplete()).filter(p -> p.isStatus()) //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
          ^
7. Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
.filter(p -> !p.isIsComplete()).filter(p -> p.isStatus()) //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                                         ^
8. Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
.filter(com.court.handler.FxUtilsHandler.distinctByKey(p -> p.getMemberLoanCode())) //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                                                         ^
9. Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
.sorted(java.util.Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getId())) //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                                         ^
10. Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
.filter(p -> !p.isIsComplete()).filter(p -> p.isStatus()) //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
          ^
11. Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
.filter(p -> !p.isIsComplete()).filter(p -> p.isStatus()) //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                                         ^
12. Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
.filter(com.court.handler.FxUtilsHandler.distinctByKey(p -> p.getMemberLoanCode())) //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
                                                         ^
12 errors

    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:204)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:512)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
```

Here is my variable expression :

```
<variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{memberLoans}.stream()
.sorted(java.util.Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getId()))
.filter(p -> !p.isIsComplete()).filter(p -> p.isStatus())
.filter(com.court.handler.FxUtilsHandler.distinctByKey(p -> p.getMemberLoanCode()))
.collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList())]]></variableExpression>
```

I already add my application jar and latest jdt-compiler jar to the classpath and changed the source to 1.8 as well but still It gives me the above mentioned error.

[image: Image_1]

[image: Image_2]

Any suggestion would be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to replace the *jtd compiler* that used by *iReport* with new version of *jtd compiler* (used by JasperReports 6.3).

The last version of *iReport* is *5.6.0* and it is using *JasperReports 5.6.0* behind the scene.

The *JasperReports 5.6* is using the *jdt 3.1*, you can find this dependency at *pom.xml*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

It means that *JasperReports API* is using the old version *jdt* that has not support for *Java 8*.

For example, the *net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler* class is using the *jdt* core. It means that changes of *jdt API* can break the compiling mechanism.

Despite these facts I continued my experiment and replace the *jdt* with new version: *4.3.1* (this version is used by JasperReports 6.3). This version allow us to use *Java 8* syntax at templates.

I also set properties at *iReport*:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8
```

But I got the error (as expected) during compiling the template (*jrxml*) via *iReport*:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getErrors()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/IProblem;     
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.ExtendedJRJdtCompiler$CompilerRequestor.acceptResult(ExtendedJRJdtCompiler.java:96)     
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:480)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler.compileUnits(JRJdtCompiler.java:167)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:201)     
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:512)
```

It means that my attempt failed, because the *jdt API* was changed in new version. But *JasperReports API* is still using "old" methods instead of methods from new *jdt.jar*.

Solutions as I see:

1. To stop using unsupported *IDE* and replace it with *Jaspersoft Studio*
2. Don't use compiling at *IDE* (*iReport*) and try to compile/test reports with *Java* code.

---

More information:

[Use lambda expressions inside TextField expression in Jaspersoft Studio 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41618362/876298)

[How to use lambda expression in jrxml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38275384/876298)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I tried with TIBCO Jaspersoft also.. but again the report is not compiling. If you need I can ask another question.

Comment: Looks stange. Did you see this link: [Use lambda expressions inside TextField expression in Jaspersoft Studio 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41618362/876298)?

Comment: I added all required jars to the project build path.. Please correct me If I do wrong. http://ibb.co/gwGagR

Comment: Did you set *org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.*=1.8* properties? I did not add jdt at libraries with my JSS 6.3.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157236/discussion-between-alex-k-and-madushan-perera).

Answer (score 0):

update JDK your computer (y)
the barbecue-1.5-beta1 jar not compiling of all jdk !